# swift and iBeacon firedate notification in locationManager

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon, locationmanager

The code below works fine for the notification. But, It is too much notification between near and far when I try the app.

```
extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
func sendLocalNotificationWithMessage(message: String!) {
    let notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = message
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didRangeBeacons beacons: AnyObject[]!,
    inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {
        NSLog("didRangeBeacons");
        var message:String = ""

        if(beacons.count > 0) {
            let nearestBeacon:CLBeacon = beacons[0] as CLBeacon

            switch nearestBeacon.proximity {
            case CLProximity.Far:
                message = "You are far away from the beacon"
            case CLProximity.Near:
                message = "You are near the beacon"
            case CLProximity.Immediate:
                message = "You are in the immediate proximity of the beacon"
            case CLProximity.Unknown:
                return
            }
        } else {
            message = "No beacons are nearby"
        }

        NSLog("%@", message)
        sendLocalNotificationWithMessage(message)
}
```

}

Is it a way to use a kind of firedate statement? Something like:

```
localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 900)
```

If I put in the "func sendLocalNotificationWithMessage", it will firedate all Notifications. I have to find somehow a way to put after the switch?

Or maybe a notification counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is delay a new notifications from showing up if you have sent another notification in the last 900 seconds.  If that is the goal, you could do something like this:

```
var lastNotificationTime = 0.0

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
  didRangeBeacons beacons: AnyObject[]!,
  inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {
    NSLog("didRangeBeacons");
    var beaconVisible = false
    var proximity = CLProximity.Unknown
    if(beacons.count > 0) {
      beaconVisible = true
      let nearestBeacon:CLBeacon = beacons[0] as CLBeacon
      proximity = nearestBeacon.proximity
    }
    else {
      beaconVisible = false
    }

    if (NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() - lastNotificationTime > 900) {
      lastNotificationTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
      var message:String = ""
      if beaconVisible {
        switch proximity {
        case CLProximity.Far:
          message = "You are far away from the beacon"
        case CLProximity.Near:
          message = "You are near the beacon"
        case CLProximity.Immediate:
          message = "You are in the immediate proximity of the beacon"
        case CLProximity.Unknown:
          return
        }
      }
      else {
        message = "No beacons are nearby";
      }
      NSLog("%@", message)
      sendLocalNotificationWithMessage(message)
    }
  }
```